# Symfony 4 without top level namespace

Tags: symfony, namespaces, symfony4

I want to migrate a Silex project to Symfony 4. I'm working on the skeleton first so I executed:

```
composer create-project symfony/skeleton myProject
```

and then required the bundles with `composer require bundle` for each one.

One of them needs some configuration to be installed, so I added a file `config/packages/custom_bundle.yaml` with such configuration.

`custom_bundle.yaml` needs a custom user provider service which I copied from the Silex project to the same namespace (`Security`) with the same name (`UserProvider.php`) so I created a service at `config/services.yaml`:

```
security.users_provider:
    class: Security\UserProvider
```

Then I tried to require the bundle again and I get this error:

> The autoloader expected class "App\Security\UserProvider" to be defined in file "/vagrant/myProject/vendor/composer/../../src/Security/UserProvider.php".
>    The file was found but the class was not in it, the class name or namespace probably has a typo in /vagrant/myProject/config/services.yaml (which is loaded in resource "/vagrant/myProject/config/services.yaml").

Of course, I have to tell composer to load classes from non-top-level-namespace so I replaced:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

in `composer.json` with:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "": "src/"
    }
},
```

But now I get this error because the `Kernel.php` namespace is `App`:

> PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "Kernel" from namespace "App".

I have the entire Silex project without top-level-namespace, so adding `App` or whatever as top-level-namespace would mean renaming the whole project classes.

By other hand, removing the `App` namespace of `Kernel.php` would mean using this class as global, which might won't be a good idea.

**Any workaround to avoid rewriting all classes namespaces?**

PS: I also tried with:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "": "src/",
    }
},
```

but same happens.

**Edit:**

The problem was the default definition of services:

```
App\:
    resource: '../src/*'
    exclude: '../src/{Entity,Migrations,Tests,Kernel.php}'
```

As I don't have the `App` namespace I've had to comment it by now. Later I'll have to add any services to be auto-defined with their namespaces. E.g.

```
Service\:
    resource: '../src/Service/*'
```

So it works with commenting the default App services definition and adding:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "Secutiry\\": "src/Secutiry/",
    }
},
```

and any other namespaces to `composer.json`. Thanks @Cerad for the tips.

**Edit2:**

Even works with:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "src/",
        "": "src/"
    }
},
```

Comment: Start by going back to the default "App\\": "src/".  From your original error message I suspect you need to change the namespace in UserProvider.php to App\Security.  I know you are trying to avoid adding App to everything but I don't see how without adding many lines to the psr4 section.  "Security\\": "/src/Security" might get you past the UserProvider error but then there will probably be others.

Comment: @Cerad - In fact, there would be much less lines to change adding a line in ps4 for each first level namespace. However I'm still getting the first error: `The autoloader expected class "App\Security\UserProvider" to be defined...`

Comment: Don't know where the App in App\Security\Provider is coming from.  The class is not being referenced from some place else as far as you know?

Comment: @Cerad thanks for your tips. I've finally found the issue. Look at the edited question.

Comment: So it was the App in the resources that was the culprit.  Good to know.

Comment: @Cerad - That's it.